# To return a pointer to struct or pass it in?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

Which of these is more efficient and better code? or is there some other way I should be doing this?

```
typedef struct foo {
int width;
int height;
} foo;
```

...this typedef in both the below examples, but its really an arbitrary structure...

```
foo *new_foo (int width, int height) {

  foo *f
  if ((f = malloc(sizeof(foo)))==NULL) return NULL;

  f->width = width;
  f->height = height;

  return foo;
}  


void del_foo (foo *f) {free(f);}


int main () {

  int width = 3;
  int height = 4; // arbitrary values

  foo *f   
  f = new_foo(width, height)

  // do something with foo here      

  del_foo(f);
}
```

or

```
int new_foo (foo *f, int width, int height) {

  f->width = width;
  f->height = height;

  return 0;
}  


int main () {

  int width = 3;
  int height = 4; // arbitrary values

  foo *f
  if ((f = malloc(sizeof(foo)))==NULL) return NULL;   
  new_foo(f, width, height)

  // do something with foo here      

  free(f);
}
```

Thanks! My apologies for any typos.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo* new_foo(int width, int height)
```

seems preferable for a function with `new` in its name (`new` will imply dynamic allocation to people with experience of C++).

```
void foo_init(foo f, int width, int height)
```

would be reasonable if you wanted to allow clients to declare `foo` objects on the stack as well as heap.  You could also choose to provide both, implementing `new_foo` as a `malloc` then a call to `foo_init`.

If you provide a function which allocates memory, it'd be reasonable to also offer a function which destroys an object - `foo_destroy(foo )` (`del_foo` in your question?)

One last, minor, point - you can more obviously group related functions if you prefix their names the struct they operate on rather than adding the struct at the end (i.e. `foo_new` is more usual than `new_foo`)

Comment: thanks, sorry that is a typo there, should be "void foo_init(foo *f, int width, int height)"!

Comment: Ok, that was quite an important typo!  I've updated my answer with a bit more info

Comment: thanks very much! and thanks for the minor point, interesting and useful info.